# Russian variable resistor datasheet

Tags: current, resistors, resistance

Can you please help me find datasheet for this 2.2 ohm variable resistor. I want to know if it can tolerate 20 amps.
If you recognize the logo that would help a lot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 20 A through 2.2 ohms would be over 800 W. Without even looking at the datasheet I can tell you this device can not handle 20 A.

Comment: @ThePhoton 2.20megaohms or 2.2ohms?

Comment: @ThePhoton OoOops, I would comment to the OP, not you dear friend. sorry.

Comment: @Roh it's 2.2 ohms, probably Russians write it like mega.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the [datasheet](http://www.radiant.su/files/images/Kontakt/ppb.pdf) for the family. Here's how you read it:

**Variables resistors wire frameless trimmers (versions
axis «Б», «В», «Д», «Е») and regulation (versions axis «А», «Г») actuators
with the circular motion of the mobile system for surface mounting, intended for use in DC and AC frequency to 1000 Hz.**

The part on the picture above is rated for **25W** nominal/long term power.

Comment: Most pots of this type have an additional wiper current limitation that may kick in. For example, Ohmite RHS2R0E 25W units are actually limited by the 3.5A maximum wiper current rather than the power dissipation rating (you can run current through the winding to get to 25W but not through the wiper). Maybe the Russian ones are more rugged, but perhaps caution is called for.

Comment: With only 1.25 volts across it, the current at full resistance will be about half an amp, nowhere near 20 amps.  Only with the wiper all but touching the source terminal would the resistance be low enough to get 20 amps through it with a mere 1.25 V potential.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That's a good point. But is my calculation correct? Or to calculate current for this particular resistor I should use P=I^2R, then the current will be 3.37A?

Comment: Your *calculation* is 100% correct (R would be 0.0625\$\Omega\$ or less than 3% of resistance- so only the first or 2nd winding would be taking all the heat).. so I'm not sure that assumption reflects reality as to what that pot can handle without damage. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisStratton So, how do we estimate the maximum long term current that this resistor could withstand?

Comment: You really need to know about the rest of the circuit; ie, if you connect it across an unlimited-current voltage-mode power supply sized with the voltage chosen to produce 25 watts at full resistance, turning the wiper towards the low resistance end would at an extreme constitute a short circuit, with obvious results.

Comment: @ScottSeidman He's saying that if you connect the pot as a rheostat and turn it almost all the way to zero ohms, the dissipation will be within the 25W specification, which is correct as far as it goes, but I think there is also an (unwritten in the case of the Russian 'data sheet') wiper current limitation.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Fair enough. ;-)

Comment: Ok, I will delete my calculation.